# allocation to a member of a custom structure (ANSI C)

Tags: c

I have this custom structure:

```
typedef struct
{
  MyType* myType;
  int one;
  char szTwo[128];
} _TheType

_TheType theType;
```

Is there a way to allocate memory to

```
theType.myType
```

somehow as in the definition of _MyType is defined as a pointer?

Comment: You can malloc a sufficient amount of memory and map the myType pointer to that or else you can malloc a memory explicitly for myType. What have you tried? I don't understand, where the problem is.

Comment: Edited, MyType is pointer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. Just use `malloc()`:

```
theType.myType = malloc(sizeof *theType.myType);
```

That gives you room (if it succeeds) for one instance. You can extend it to an array if that's what you want, by simply scaling the `sizeof` expression.

The fact that the `myType` pointer is a member of a structure doesn't matter, this is the same as you'd do it for any other dynamic memory allocation.

Remember to `free()` the pointer when you're done with it, and never access it after doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're familiar with the `malloc` and `free` functions in the standard library, just do:

```
theType.myType = malloc(sizeof(MyType));


// once you're done with theType
free(theType.myType);
```

edit:

if this is C++, not C then:

```
typedef struct
{
  MyType* myType;
  int one;
  char szTwo[128];

  _TheType() : myType(new MyType) {}
  ~TheType() { delete myType; }
} _TheType;
```

Which will allocate on the creation of _TheType and deallocate on its destruction

Comment: I tried it though a compiler error occurred: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'struct _MyType *'
                                                                   Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast

Comment: Forget it, I was misreading the question!  I thought he was also asking how to access members of the type.